# Train MFCC using Machine Learning Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, binary-tree, classification, mfcc

I have a datasets of MFCC that I know is good. I know how to put a row vector into a machine learning algorithm. My question is how to do it with MFCC, as it is a matrix? For example, how would I put this inside a machine learning algorithm:?

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00195/Test_Arabic_Digit.txt

Any algorithm will work. I am looking at a binary classifier, but will be looking into it more. Scikit seems like a good resource. For now I would just like to know how to input MFCC into an algorithm. Step by step would help me a lot! I have looked in a lot of places but have not found an answer.

Thank you

Comment: So what do you want to do? Pass the sound file A as features and B as classes?

Comment: I rephrased my question for clarity. The question now includes a link. My dataset looks just like that and I am wondering how to feed that into a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: Again, in the link you provided, there are a bunch of numbers, what is it? Why is there an empty line between those bunch of numbers? Are classification target classes in there? Explain the data

Comment: Each block represents a sound file. Each line is a small part of such sound file (20-40ms) and each column represents the coefficients of the mel frequencies cepstra (hence MFCC). 

The empty lines separate the sound files. I am thinking of creating a column for the classification target classes, but am not sure how to label it yet because there are multiple lines for each sound file.

Comment: Does each line in a chunk is from same timeframe for all sound files. Or random?

Comment: The first line of each block represents a time frame, e.g. 0-30ms, the second line will be 20ms-50ms, and so on.

Comment: Ok. Means all chunks correspond to same time-frames. Right? Then you can expand all chunks into single vector. Which will be feature vector for that file. Do this for all files and you will get your training data

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, thank you. What if I don't have the same time frame for all sound files yet? What are methods to do that?

Comment: Depends on the type of classification problem you are solving. For example, if finding the nature of a sound (for example music) I think that even if same time frame for all files are not present, it can give satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can easily flatten a matrix so it becomes in a vector,for example you can use numpy and numpy's flatten function ,additionally an idea that comes to my mind(it's just an idea may or may not work) is to use convolutions, convolutions work very well with 2d structures.